# Creating a "Workbook.Connections("MyDBx").ODBCConnection" from a UserDSN or an ODBC file

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

Excel 2016 on a Windows 10 Pro computer: I can open a workbook and from the

> DATA / From Other Sources / Data Connection Wizard / odbc DSN

where I select my User DSN and supply additional info.

It then creates the VBA code to set up a connection between my computer and an external SQL data base. I have previously defined a UserDSN for this connection.

If I record this process I end up with something like this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MyDBx").ODBCConnection
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .CommandType = xlCmdSql
  .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=SQL2;"
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .SavePassword = False
  .SourceConnectionFile = "D:\MyDocs\My Data Sources\Mydbx.odc"
  .SourceDataFile = ""
  .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
  .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=SQL2;" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
  .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM `MyDBx`.`tablea`")
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .PreserveFormatting = True
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
  .PreserveColumnInfo = True
  .SourceConnectionFile = "D:\MyDocs\My Data Sources\MyDBx.odc"
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

This works and I can follow it with the VBA code to analyze and plot the data.
However, if I delete the sheet created above and then try to rerun the macro, it will fail on the statement

> With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MyDBx").ODBCConnection

There is also a warning when I delete the above sheet, that the sheet to be deleted contains a query.

How to capture/create the code in a macro which will allow my macro to run in a new/blank workbook using the above data connection.

Obviously I can keep the sheet and always run the macro in that workbook, but not in another workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to build it object by object like this:

```
Private Sub NewWorkbookWithODBCConnection()
    Dim myWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim myWorkbookConnection As WorkbookConnection
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myQuerytable As QueryTable

    Set myWorkBook = Workbooks.Add

    Set myWorkbookConnection = myWorkBook.Connections.Add2( _
        Name:="MyDBx", _
        Description:="Whatever", _
        ConnectionString:="ODBC;DSN=SQL2;", _
        CommandText:="")

    With myWorkbookConnection.ODBCConnection
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .CommandType = xlCmdSql
      .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=SQL2;"
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .SavePassword = False
      .SourceConnectionFile = "D:\MyDocs\My Data Sources\Mydbx.odc"
      .SourceDataFile = ""
      .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
      .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With

    Set myWorksheet = myWorkBook.Worksheets.Add

    Set myQuerytable = myWorksheet.ListObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=0, _
        Source:="ODBC;DSN=SQL2;", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

    With myQuerytable
      .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM `MyDBx`.`tablea`")
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .PreserveColumnInfo = True
      .SourceConnectionFile = "D:\MyDocs\My Data Sources\MyDBx.odc"
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, I'll try to get to try this out before the weekend.

Comment: I just created a module using your code as a guide and it works perfectly.  I need to study some more to better understand what you proposed, but for now "many thanks".